# Dynamics CRM: how to create service endpoints

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm

I've custom entity and I want to define service endpoint for it in the CRM.
Is it possible make this from the CRM UI or do I need to develop custom plugin?

Sultan

Comment: Can you embellish on why you need to create a service endpoint for it?  This is not that common of an operation so I want to see if there might be a better way to go about getting what you want.

Comment: I've custom entity e.. Applications and I want to be able to create and view the applications from SharePoint, it is good enough?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you want exactly, but you could create a custom application and connect to the CRM web services using the SDK to do any CRUD or other supported operation to the CRM data/schema.  You could create a custom web service abstraction layer the same way you create any web services, include the SDK DLL's, and make calls to the underlying CRM web service.

Comment: Thanks @Cole Chamberlain I try to code less as much as possible. So now I'll play around with CRM and SharePoint SDKs.)